# Using flex to stop elements from overlapping on the same line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have mocked up my issue whereby I have a dropdown that includes "added" options (in black boxes) like so: Can I use flex to stop an option splitting over two lines and them bunching up all of the time? I could have any number of options depending on the users input.

```css
.dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
  margin: 0.125rem 0rem 0rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.options-wrapper {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.option {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <span class="option">Accepted</span>
    <span class="option">In progress</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

They should behave like so:
[image]

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear. Why aren't you just using divs for the option elements?

Comment: How so? 3 people have managed to understand the requirements and provide solutions?

Comment: Three people took guesses. I started to, but doubted my interpretation. Based on the downvotes I'm not alone. The image helped.

Comment: In particular I was confused by the min-width rule. That didn't make sense to me given the flexible nature of the options and the only slightly larger container width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use flex to solve this.

All changes were made in `.options-wrapper` using flex. Also one addition to `.option` to add margin. I also commented out the `max-width` to mimic your image.

```css
.dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  /* max-width: 150px; */
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
  margin: 0.125rem 0rem 0rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.options-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.option {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  min-width: 120px;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <span class="option">Accepted</span>
    <span class="option">In progress</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
  margin: 0.125rem 0rem 0rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.options-wrapper {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}

.option {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <span class="option">Accepted</span>
    <span class="option">In progress</span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some explanation of what you changed or added would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add display=inline-block to your span elements.  also add margin-bottom if you want some separation.

```css
.dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: normal;
  padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
  margin: 0.125rem 0rem 0rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.options-wrapper {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px; 
}

.option {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  min-width: 120px;
}

span{
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:2px;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="options-wrapper">
    <span class="option">Accepted</span>
    <span class="option">In progress</span>
  </div>
</div>
```